# Input to table in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can i add a content to html table with input fields.
For example here is html code:

```js
        function add(){
            var name = document.getElementById("name");
            var surname = document.getElementById("surname");
            var output = document.getElementById("output");
            output.innerHTML = "<tr><td>"+name+"</td><td>"+surname+"</td></tr>"


        }
```

```html
  

  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <style>
            table,td{
                border: 1px solid black;
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <form action="">
            <div>
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="name">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="name">Surname</label>
                <input type="text" id="surname">
            </div>
        </form>
        <input type="button" onclick="add();" value="Add">
        <div>
            <table id="output">
                <thead><td>Name</td><td>Surname</td></thead>
                <tbody></tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

I want to output my input fields in the table like rows.. but it does not work i dont know where is my problem i get [object HTMLInputElement].
And how can i make it work for entering more values because like this i can only enter one row

Comment: `name.value` and `surname.value`. `name` and `surname` are HTML elements represented as JS Objects.

Comment: How can i fix not changing the table heading

Comment: Put the `id` on the `tbody` instead of `table`.

Comment: Another problem now i can only input one item i want to store the previous items ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using this code?
It adds surname and name below the `thead`.

```js
function add(){
  var name = document.getElementById("name");
  var surname = document.getElementById("surname");
  var output = document.querySelector("#output tbody");
  output.innerHTML += "<tr><td>"+name.value+"</td><td>"+surname.value+"</td></tr>"
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        table,td{
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="">
        <div>
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="name">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="name">Surname</label>
            <input type="text" id="surname">
        </div>
    </form>
    <input type="button" onclick="add();" value="Add">
    <div>
        <table id="output">
            <thead><td>Name</td><td>Surname</td></thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but i have more in my question how can i make it work for entering multiple times ?

Comment: I will edit my answer.

Comment: You can check my answer now.

Comment: nice ty can you explain how this works, i mean what did you changed in the js ?

Comment: no need ty i figure it out

Comment: `output.innerHTML = "<tr><td>"+name.value+"</td><td>"+surname.value+"</td></tr>"` this is first code. and `output.innerHTML += "<tr><td>"+name.value+"</td><td>"+surname.value+"</td></tr>"` this is code now. Change is `+`. This code adds new line to your table. :)

Answer (score 1):

you should assign the value of the input fields like below.

```
 function add(){
            var name = document.getElementById("name");
            var surname = document.getElementById("surname");
            var output = document.getElementById("output");
            output.innerHTML = "<tr><td>"+name.value+"</td><td>"+surname.value+"</td></tr>"
        }
```

Comment: Oh yea but it changes the table heading

Comment: yeah that's different issue now :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try:
Give `tbody` an id to avoid removing `thead`

```HTML
<tbody id="output2"></tbody>
```

```js
function add(){
  var name = document.getElementById("name");
  var surname = document.getElementById("surname");
  var output = document.getElementById("output2");
  output.innerHTML = "<tr><td>" + name.value + "</td><td>" + surname.value + "</td></tr>";
}
```

You are trying to insert an HTML input element instead of the **value** of the element.
To make multiple entries possible try the last line of the function to:

```js
output.innerHTML += "<tr><td>" + name.value + "</td><td>" + surname.value + "</td></tr>";
```

Comment: but i have more in my question how can i make it work for entering multiple times ?

Comment: check last edit

Comment: yep ty it works